# Present sheet with fullscreen parent view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to make a sheet in my SwiftUI app. My problem is that my parent view appears minimized and I want it to appear in fullscreen.

**What I want:**

[image: What I want]

**What I get:**

[image: What I get]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This is for UIKit, but anyway, I found that doing `self.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` itself doesn't work.

Instead, you need start with a normal view controller, than present a view controller that is `presentedVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`. Then, when you present from *that* view controller, you will get the desired overlaid result.

---

If you set the parent view controller's `modalPresentationStyle`, it should work

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

[image: full screen present sheet]

Comment: Thank for your answer but that is the good way to do it in UIKit but I want to do that in SwiftUI